# Tee all SSH Session Output (by default)

Tags: ssh

Currently I am trying to do something similar to what PuTTY does on Windows. I want to capture ssh session info. I want to be able to see stdout in a log file based on the hour, and separate the logs based on host. Now tee works well but you will always need to remember to type out tee and the date and directory. Thats just not really practical. Does someone know of a way to do what I am asking? I looked into adding the Local command option to my ssh configs but that as you would imagine it is not(cannot) be used to capture output as it appears to run the command after the ssh session starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper that you would use instead of `ssh`
command. It could be:

```
tssh() { ssh "$@" | tee "$(date +%m_%Y_%H:%M:%S)"; }
```

You can now use `tssh` with all options you would normally use with
`ssh`. SSH session will be logged to a file, for example
`08_2019_16:43:50`. See `man date` for explanation of `+` format
specifiers.

However, it's harder to embed host name in the name of the output log
file. You can use a wrapper like that but you need to remember to
always pass host as the first parameter:

```
tssh()
{
    if [ ! "$#" -eq 1 ]
    then
    printf "Error: Host missing\n" >&2
    return 0
    fi

    ssh "$@" | tee "$1_$(date +%m_%Y_%H:%M:%S)"
}
```

For example:

```
   $ tssh localhost -vv
   $ logout
```

Output log file will contain hostname in its name, for example:

```
   localhost_08_2019_16:47:41
```

Comment: Thats pretty clean, I like it. I think I can ake it a bit further and maybe make a folder per host and place the log file in that folder. Just for some simple house keeping. A little mkdir -p would handle new hosts too. Thank you Arkadiusz, that should help me get started.

Comment: Ok. You can now mark this [question as
answered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to let
other users know your problem is solved.